# Splunk logging on multiple dynamic instances

Tags: splunk

I have an application of which new server instances would be increasing upon increasing load.

Now as per app config - the log files would remain physically inside these newly created server instances.

How can I feed logs of these newly created server instances to Splunk?

Should I log at a common known location for ALL of these newly created server instances?

OR

there is a better approach.
Please advice.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The preferred way is to install the Splunk Universal Forwarder (UF) on each server instance and have the UF send the logs to Splunk.

Comment: but what to do in the scenario where the server (kub pod) is added as an instance dynamically?...  in those scenarios where .. where you don't even know the  newly created server name

Comment: @reverse - then you following this guide for prepping a UF for such an environment: https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Forwarder/latest/Forwarder/Makeauniversalforwarderpartofahostimage